# Kendoui grid batch edit error: kendo.all.min.js SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am facing a very annoying problem with the **kendoui grid of kendo-ui version 2013.1.514.**
Following the demo on http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html I created a small demo app for updating employees in a database.
Pretty simple.
Now as soon as I add or update some employee in the grid and press save, the server handlers are called as expected and everything works fine. However, when the handlers are done, back on the client I get this awful script **error: "kendo.all.min.js SCRIPT1004: Expected';'"**

I already searched through the web and all i found for this problem was that you should make sure, you load the KENDO and other JS scripts in the right order.
However, as I am using the KENDO project template for MVC, I never changed anything in the order of the js files, as they were already created by the project wizard.

I also added a sample solution, that you can get from: http://sdrv.ms/12x0Zw3

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to include some fiddle, it is hard to guess what is going wrong. Either way I don't think the issue is because of the js files order, you wouldn't make it pass the doc ready event. It sounds to me like you update is not returning correct values back to the grid.

Comment: Try changing the version of kendo you are using. Use the CDN for a quick test.

http://cdn.kendostatic.com/<version>/js/<filename>.min.js

e.g.http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. figured it out.

In my action methods I just returned the viewmodels that were passed in.

However, the grid expects the updated viemodels (e.g.: viewmodel for added item has id==0 when it comes in, but should be returned with a valid id > 0)

An excellent description can be found in the docs of telerik:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/batch-editing